# vtiger 7.5 how to add dynamic picklist to module add new/edit form

Tags: dynamic-picklist-vtiger

vtiger 7.5 how to add dynamic picklist to module add new/edit form.
dynamic means data from DB table. e.g from Vendors table

Tried with manifest.xml to that module, but didnt work out.